# Why is __init__.py not being called?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7 and have the following files:

```
./__init__.py
./aoeu.py
```

`__init__.py` has the following contents:

```
aoeu aoeuaoeu aoeuaoeuaoeu
```

so I would expect running aoeu.py to error when Python tries to load `__init__.py`, but it doesn't.  The behavior is the same whether PYTHONPATH is set to '.' or unset.

What's going on?

Comment: does the filename contain the __ or not ?

Comment: @ankur: that was a relic of how SO treats `__`

Comment: @wooble should have read your comment a little earlier ... did the mistake myself below ... :( ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`__init__.py` makes the enclosing directory a package. It won't be executed unless you actually try to import the package directly.

Comment: or a module of that package or a sub-package

Comment: The comment by `mg` is so essential! It is a better practice to keep `__init__.py` rather empty to avoid cricular imports.