# How to bypass __init__.py when unittest a module in a package by using pytest?

Tags: python

I have a file structure similar to the following:

```
app/
 |--- __init__.py
 |--- module_under_test.py
test/
 |--- test_module.py
```

I want to unittest a module in a package by using pytest. When I import the module in my test file, the code in the __init__.py gets executed. However I want to bypass the code in the __init__.py file because in __init__.py other external dependencies are used. One way I can think of is mocking all necessary objects in __init__.py by using patch.

What is the best practise to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The thought that immediately comes to mind is: Shouldn’t the unittest mimic the app’s natural code execution?  In that case, it seems illogical for a test to subvert code.

Comment: @S3DEV The code executed in __init__.py calls irrelevant external dependencies. These external dependencies are used by other modules in the package. I don't want to call these external dependencies every time a unit test is ran for the module of interest.

Comment: I think modules that are imported should not execute code upon import. Maybe wrap that "calling external dependencies" code in a function or similar and execute when needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to avoid invoking `__init__.py` file, there is a rather dirty workaround. For the given directory structure:

```
app/
 |--- __init__.py
 |--- module_under_test.py
test/
 |--- test_module.py
```

Add at the top of the `test_module.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../app')

from module_under_test import some_function
```

Inspired by [How to import a module but ignoring the package's __init__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763985/how-to-import-a-module-but-ignoring-the-packages-init-py)