# Is it possible to import a single module from a Python package?

Tags: python

I have a python package called `utils`. It consists of a few modules, and an `__init__.py` file tying them all together.

```
__init__.py:
    from .modA import util1
    from .modB import util2
    from .modC import util3

modA.py:
    def util1():
        print("Util 1")

modB.py:
    import flask               # <-- Note this import
    def util2():
        print("Util 2")

modC.py:
    def util3():
        print("Util 3")
```

When the software is running that imports this package, it's running in a virtual environment that has flask installed, so everything works fine.

The problem I'm having is that if I interactively run `python` in my shell, and do something like `from utils.modC import util3`, even though modC has absolutely no reliance on modB, and doesn't import, or use flask, I'm still going to get an error that modB couldn't import flask (assuming I didn't activate the virtual environment in my shell first).

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 27 2020, 14:15:17) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from utils.modC import util3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/USERNAME/test/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .modB import util2
  File "/Users/USERNAME/test/utils/modB.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Without modifying the source code of the package, is there any way for me to import `util3` without having `flask` in my `sys.path` (AKA without it trying to import everything listed in `__init__.py`)?

Failing that, is there any simple way to modify `__init__.py` to allow this?

Comment: Add ```try/except``` in ```__init__.py```?

Comment: Related? [How to import a module but ignoring the package's \__init__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763985/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kaspersky pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764223/6423456), you can do it in a dirty way:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("utils")
>>> from modC import util3
>>> util3()
Util 3
```

Or use the PYTHONPATH env variable to modify `sys.path` indirectly.

This works because when you run `from modC import util3`, Python will start looking through `sys.path` for a module or package named `modC`, which is different than when we ran `from utils.modC import util3`, where it was looking for a module or package named `utils`. Appending the string `utils` to `sys.path` tells it to look there as a last resort, and because there are no other places it will find `modC`, it will eventually find it there and load it as a module, rather than a package.

This apparently won't work in some cases, but works for me.