# Python 3.5.2 logger configuration and usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm new to python and trying to setup a logger in my simple app.

This is the app structure:

```
 - checker
      - checking
         - proxy_checker.py
      - custom_threading
         - __init__.py
         - executor_my.py
         - long_task.py
      - tests
      - __init__.py
      - logging_config.ini
      - main.py
```

i'm trying to setup the file configured logger 
in the main module's `checker/__init__.py`**:**

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
```

**logging_config.ini**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=stream_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

and the use it in the `/checker/custom_threading/exector_my.py`:

```
import concurrent.futures
import logging

from custom_threading.long_task import LongTask


class MyExecutor(object):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    _executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500)

    def __init__(self, thread_count, task):
        self._thread_count = thread_count
        self._task = LongTask(task)
        pass

    def start(self):
        self.logger.debug("Launching with thread count: " + str(self._thread_count))

*more irrelevant code*
```

tried to use logger.info / logger.debug.
for both options **i don't get any error and nothing is logged in console**. What do i do wrong?

P.S. maybe also useful that i run it on Win 10 x64

Comment: How is the `MyExecutor.start()` method called?

Comment: in the `main.py` -> `executor = MyExecutor(thread_count, _proxy_checker.check_countries_in_proxylist)
    executor.start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My (possibly wrong :-) guess is that you start the script by something like `python checker/main.py`, thus the logging configuration in `__init__.py` is not executed.

Please, take a look at this answer:
[Why is __init__.py not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533480/why-is-init-py-not-being-called)

Moreover, you need to ensure that `fileConfig()` is called before `getLogger()` (class body is executed at the time of import). A working setup would be to load the configuration somewhere at the beginning of `main.py` and instantiate the logger in `MyExecutor.__init__()`.

Comment: starting as `python main.py` while in `/checker` dir. which i think the same.

Where should i set the `fileConfig('logging_config.ini')` then, based on the good practice? just in the `main.py` ?

But also, just tried to set it in `main.py` - same result.

Comment: Hmm, could you please try to also remove `__name__` inside `getLogger`?

Comment: Updated the answer with another change needed. If this still doesn't suffice then the last comment is also worth trying, but that's a more subtle thing.

Comment: yes i did tried without `__name__`, same.
also sure that the config is loaded before `getLogger()`

Comment: I found one interesting thing. I run this proj in pycharm. in `tests` folder - `pytest` test for `main.py`. When i configure pycharm to execute the `pytest` tests, and the `test_main.py` is doing `assert` on the method which is calling the executor - i see the logs in console. However, if i just run `main.py` or run the test by `pytest` command in console - no logs in console.

Comment: Did you try to move the `logger = getLogger()` line into `MyExecutor.__init__()` (obviously as `self.logger = ...`) together with moving the `fileConfig()` call to the beginning of the `main.py`? Seems to work for me. ;-)

Comment: right. it worked. strange, why it wasn't assigned when i just put `logger = getLogger()`  right after `class MyExecutor(object):` ?

Comment: It was assigned (to the class), but before `fileConfig` had a chance to execute (unless you'd put it before `import custom_threading.executor_my`).